# All Tags Not Showing on Mac Right Click

Tags: mac, finder, contextual-menu

Ok, this is a simple one that has been bugging me for months. I've searched here, Google, everywhere for an answer. There is plenty of info about creating tags, changing the names/colors, assigning tags to Finder folders, even customizing the right click menu itself.

My tags just disappeared from the right click, not the tags section, just the tag color bubbles themselves. I could always click on the 'Tags...' button and that would load a tags dialog that I could then select the tags I wanted, but to more quickly tag I should see them below that.

Comment: how to hide and show togs in the Finder right-click menu: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387849/remove-tags-section-from-macos-finder-right-click-context-menu

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally, just annoyed one night I called Apple support since I still have coverage on my new Macbook. The lady struggled just like me, no articles there about it, couldn't figure out. But after about 30 mins of poking around, she figured it out. And it's WAY simple.

1. Go to Finder > Preferences
2. Click on the Tags menu option
3. Here you will see a list where you can show/hide in your sidebar
4. Below that there is a little box, you can DRAG the tags from the upper section to the lower section which determines which tags show in your right click.

That's it. Simple. I'm dumb. Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: Jeff thanks. Same experience for me. My Tags Index got thrown off by using Path Finder Labels so I deleted them only to find the previous colors did not return. Thanks for the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem after upgrading to current High Sierra. Green and Red tags did not appear in the Finder sidebar but previously tagged folders and documents did appear when "All Tags..." was selected from the Finder sidebar. Likewise, if I selected "Documents" in the Finder sidebar the previously tagged folders and documents appeared along with their previously tagged colors. I solved this by deselecting each previously tagged folder/document and then reselecting the desired color tag. Also, the red and green tag selections did not appear in the Finder sidebar, but these were easily added by just dragging them to the sidebar and placing them in the desired order under "Tags" in the sidebar.