# Remove 'Tags' section from macOS Finder right-click context menu

Tags: finder, customization, shortcut-menu, finder-tag, contextual-menu

When I right-click an item in Finder, the context menu has a Tags section containing colored tags:

[image: macOS Finder context menu Tags]

> Tags...

In previous versions of macOS / OS X, the section was called "Labels".

I don't use Tags in Finder, so the Tags section adds 3 vertical menu items of wasted space. The colored tag dots also stretch small menus pretty far to the right.

Is there any way to hide the Tags section when right-clicking files and folders in Finder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finder > Preferences > Tags

you'll see the text:

> Drag your favorite tags to the area below **to make them available for quick use in Finder menus.**

**Drag** the tag dots *out* of the bottom "Favorite Tags" section.

If you remove all of the Favorite Tags, the Tags menu will be hidden from Finder right-click context menus.

[image: Finder Preferences > Tags]

> Add a tag to the shortcut menu: Select the tag in the list, then drag it over the tag you want to replace in the favorites section at the bottom of the window. There can be up to seven tags in the shortcut menu that appears when you Control-click a file.
>
> Remove a tag from the shortcut menu: Drag the tag out of the Favorite Tags section until you see the remove sign (X).
>
> https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/tag-files-and-folders-mchlp15236/mac